# How do I register users if they have a valid id in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, validation

I don't know how to ask the question better but it might help if I explain my problem:

I created a register page on php and after i click the register button it saves it into the database BUT what I want to do now is have like a student id inside the database and only allow users if they inputted a valid student id. The registration would look like:

First Name: 
Last Name: 
Student ID:

I don't know if I should:

1. Put a predetermined list of student ids as a primary key and let the php compare the student id and if it is a match with no entry to the first name or last name, it will just input it into the first name and last name.

Kinda like if I register "Mark Go 201853" the code will look if there is a 201853 in the student table  and if it already has a name, it will say "User with this id already exists" but if there are no First and Last names it will put Mark Go in the column of the emp id "201853" under the row of First name and Last Name.

2. Have a separate list of valid student ids in the database and after registration, it picks a student id from that list and drops it from the valid student id table and inputs it into the student table together with the First Name and Last Name
3. Your suggestions if my ideas aren't the way to do it.

I'm sorry but I did my best to google this problem but it's kinda hard so after reading slightly related topics I just came up with ideas on achieving this but if you guys could suggest a better way I would be more than happy to hear it. I'm not asking for any codes or something, I just want to know what to do first so I could code it and possibly asking here again on my progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually there will be a unique column that determines a user. It may be a username, email or a phone number etc. Name may similar but username cannot. So you have to add a unique column to the table. If a new registration comes, always check this unique column for duplicate entries.

Comment: The unique column (which is also my primary key) is the column "student_id". My problem now is I have a list of valid ids and I should ensure that only valid ids from that list are allowed to register. Now my problem is where do I put that list? Do I put it on a separate table that will drop ids after php gets one from it? Or do I put the list on the student table immediately and just let php compare if the applicant entered a valid id and will check if there's a value in the First and Last name and if there isn't, it puts the applicant's first and last name in the student table?

Comment: Better to put the ids in seperate table. After using it mark it as used (for this add a flag column). Keeping the ids in separate table allows you to manage(CRUD) it independently.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I haven't thought about creating a used column but your idea makes so much sense than dropping columns, with this, I could create a simple php to ask admins for valid ids from new registered students and manage them effectively! Thanks again I think I'll be doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kiren's answer, which takes care of duplicate ID case, I'd recommend you add some server-side logic in PHP that checks if the given student ID is a valid submission. Since this logic can be as complex as necessary, this is a more robust solution than creating a database with whitelist of student IDs. It is slightly easier to modify code to verify if a student ID is valid than it is to repeatedly add to a whitelist of "good IDs."

For example, your PHP could ensure that the student ID only contains numeric characters, and is less than the maximum possible value storable by your database.

Comment: This looks like a good way to do it, do I put the logic on the registration php itself with ||s to check if they can be registered? I'm a little worried, however, when a new valid id comes since I need to input it inside the code every time a student enrolls.

Comment: Sadly, I can't check two answers but I did upvote jpp's answer. Thanks again to everyone who helped